# OS X installation problem rosmake: command not found

Tags: osx, macos-snowleopard, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to install ROS with the set of instructions. But I got this error.

[robot_model_tutorials] Updating /Users/Tony/ros/robot_model_tutorials
[robot_model_tutorials] Done.
(Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /Users/Tony/ros
Bootstrapping ROS build
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
:15: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
File "", line 15
with open(filename, "r") as f:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
/bin/sh: rosmake: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 16, in 
sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv))
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall/rosinstall_cli.py", line 228, in rosinstall_main
options.catkinpp)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall/rosinstall_cmd.py", line 100, in cmd_generate_ros_files
subprocess.check_call("source %s && rosmake ros%s --rosdep-install%s" % (os.path.join(path, 'setup.sh'), ros_comm_insert, rosdep_yes_insert), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 462, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/Tony/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 127

Moved the Macports /opt/local folder as recommended.
Everything else was installed smoothly.
Got no idea what to do next.
Anything related to flags exporting?
Please help me.
Thank you a lot!!

OS X: 10.6.8
Xcode: 4.2 (for Snow Leopard).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44072/os-x-installation-problem-rosmake:-command-not-found/) by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-09-18**:
Sorry ... you followed [these](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) instructions? Also, which part of these install process did you get to when this failed? Did you get as far as 1.4 Environment Setup? If so, make sure you are calling setup.bash.

**Comment by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on 2012-09-18**:
No, as by tag, I tried to install Electric, because is suppossed to be more stable than Fuerte in OSX. The instructions I followed are these ones [Electric installation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation) using Homebrew,not Macports. Got till 1.6.Rosinstall Desktop-full fails.

**Comment by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on 2012-09-18**:
@Jakub. Nope 2.7.3 it is.
localhost:~ Tony$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > 

Btw I installed python27 with macports.

**Comment by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) on 2012-09-18**:
@Tony. From error log above that your ROS installation is at Python 2.6 source tree: File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall/rosinstall_cmd.py".   If you have already python2.7 try to remove and reinstall ROS to put it in 2.7 tree.

**Comment by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on 2012-09-19**:
Try to install again and now the directory of 2.6 doesn't exists. sudo easy_install pip requests that directory. I created a new one at the same place /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/. But how do you exactly use the -d option? I've tried sudo easy_install pip -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

**Comment by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) on 2012-09-19**:
If dir 2.6 does not exists any more it should not be needed. Try to upgrade easy_installl to the new version.

**Comment by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on 2012-09-19**:
@Jakub
Did it, the result is described in the update below.

**Comment by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) on 2012-09-19**:
@TonyGon Check the update of my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Update.**
Well, we're getting somewhere.
Updated pip, installed everything. No errors. Then point [1.6 Rosinstall](http://ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew#electric.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-rosinstall.rosinstall) came along.
Got the "no gtest Formula" error, but created one as in [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/42335/mac-os-x-install-error-no-available-formula-for-gtest/).
I installed vcstools, and when I ran desktop-full rosinstall I got 2 built errors. Then didn't change anything, ran the install again, and got 1 error, then again 2, strange.
This is from the log output file.

> [ rosmake ] Output from build of
> package roslib written to: 
> [ rosmake ]
> /Users/Tony/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120920-024140/roslib/build_output.log
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib [FAIL]
> [ 2.54 seconds ]
> [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in
> package roslib.  [ rosmake ] Waiting
> for other threads to complete.
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits
> [PASS] [ 1.23 seconds ]
> [ rosmake ] Results:
> [ rosmake ] Built 7 packages with 1
> failures.
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to
> directory
> [ rosmake ]
> /Users/Tony/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120920-024140
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/rosinstall",
> line 16, in 
> sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv))   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosinstall/rosinstall_cli.py",
> line 228, in rosinstall_main
> options.catkinpp)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosinstall/rosinstall_cmd.py",
> line 100, in cmd_generate_ros_files
> subprocess.check_call("source %s && rosmake ros%s --rosdep-install%s" %
> (os.path.join(path, 'setup.sh'),
> ros_comm_insert, rosdep_yes_insert),
> shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')  
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 511, in check_call
> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) subprocess.CalledProcessError:
> Command 'source
> /Users/Tony/ros/setup.sh && rosmake
> ros ros_comm --rosdep-install'
> returned non-zero exit status 1

Getting closer every time...
rosemacs, rospack, rosbuild, roslang, cpp_common, roscpp_traits were [Built].
roslib [Build Fail] . 
and the rest reads as [Not Built]

What are your thoughts on this one?, Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) with karma: 41 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-09-19**:
What he said ^^^.

**Comment by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on 2012-09-19**:
@WilliamWoodall
Yes, my bad, I tried it but it didn't work, so I deleted everything and installed again, but the error about python 2.6 is still coming up.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-09-19**:
Wait so what are you doing here?  Trying to install pip?

**Comment by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on 2012-09-19**:
Well now I am, yes.
After deleting everything and starting from scratch.
And I got only till the pip installation.
Will try Jakub's updated advise, and let you know guys.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-09-19**:
That doesn't really tell me anything, the above error occurs because `rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install` failed.  `rosmake` failed because roslib failed to build.  You can look at the log file it output, or you can run `roscd roslib` and then `make` to get the raw output.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-09-19**:
Also, you can just call `rosmake ros ros_comm` in the future rather than calling rosinstall each time.

**Comment by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on 2012-09-19**:
Well, then where can I find more information about the error so you can help me out?
The command rosmake is not found, and roscd doesn't work cuz ther's no roslib package, it failed. =S

**Comment by [TonyGon](https://answers.ros.org/users/3224/tonygon/) on 2012-09-20**:
@Jakub & @WilliamWoodall.
Thank you guys for your help.
I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 in Parallels and got it over with.
Browsing the tutorials now.
Too bad I couldn't install it in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you use python2.6. Try to upgrade python to version 2.7. Should do the trick.

---

The problem is the *easy_install* in itself. As you can see in the error log: "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6".

You have to upgrade first the *setuptools* package that contains *easy_install*.  Check the http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools how to install.

You should have *setuptools* in version 0.6c11 to be compatible with *python2.7*

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-09-18**:
Or find where that is getting called and add `from __future__ import with_statement`